# LinqToExcel dot in header

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-excel

Using linqtoexcel to read a server generated spreadsheet.  Only problem is that there is a dot in one of the headers and it refuses to pull.  Manufacturer is abbreviated to Mfg.  I used the following code per the example on their page

```
        ExcelQueryFactory excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
        excel.FileName = myXLFile;
        excel.AddMapping<Part>(x => x.Manufacturer, "Mfg.");
        var parts = from x in excel.Worksheet<Part>(0)
                    select x;
```

but Manufacturer comes up empty in all the objects.  I am very new to Linq so not sure what options I might have to make this work.  I imagine it is confused by the dot when it tries to map to a Part object...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is apparent from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/linqtoexcel/column$20name/linqtoexcel/qMfHw5L7RXE/Jj9xwIZewgkJ) thread in Linq To Excel's discussion group you have to replace the dot by a hash:

```
excel.AddMapping<Part>(x => x.Manufacturer, "Mfg#");
```

Comment: That did it.  Thank you, I searched quite a bit and never found that.